# How to use rails route helpers to point to a different host?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

As written in the [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers):

> In the case of `resources :photos`:
>
> `photos_path` returns `/photos`
>
> ...
>
> Each of these helpers has a corresponding _url helper (such as photos_url) which returns the same path prefixed with the current host, port and path prefix.

I want to use `photos_url` to point to a different host (not the current host).

I am able to append URL params to this path, but setting a `:host` has no effect, ie:

```
photos_path(host: 'localhost:3000', utm_source: 'source')
# => http://localhost:3001/photos?utm_source=source
```

It just takes the current host

Answer (score 2):

`photos_url(host: 'localhost:3000', utm_source: 'source')` should work fine

`photos_path` returns the path, and does not contain the host (/photos?utm_source=source)